How to detect and do something when a file loaded in the browser during page load
How to wait for a file (eg. "sunny.png") and send an alert, when it's loaded using JavaScript.
network tab example
My original intention was to just wait for the whole page to load, but DOMContentLoaded and document.readyState were all very early, with window.onload the page was still loaded and the event didn't fire. I have to wait for the last file to load. I don't have access to edit the original page.

How do you know that window.onload does not work? According to mdn:  "The load event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets, scripts, iframes, and images."

I tried in developer tools, the page was still loading and the event never fired. The console log, which is shown in the mdn as an example, didn't happen.

You can use the Image object in JavaScript to load an image and then use the onload event to trigger an alert when the image is fully loaded. Here's an example:
const img = new Image();
img.src = 'sunny.png';

img.onload = function() {
  alert('Image loaded!');
};
   // If the image is already in the cache, manually trigger the onload event
if (img.complete) {
   img.onload();
}

In this example, img.onload is a function that will be called when the image is fully loaded. The alert function will then display an alert message saying "Image loaded!".

The alert comes too early, before the image is loaded.

@mauna
The issue with the alert appearing too early may be due to the browser caching the image. When an image is loaded from the cache, the onload event can be triggered almost immediately, sometimes before the JavaScript has fully set up the event listener.
To ensure the alert only triggers after the image is fully loaded, you can use the following approach to check if the image is already cached, and if so, manually trigger the onload callback:
// If the image is already in the cache, manually trigger the onload event
if (img.complete) {
img.onload();
}

You can simply use onload function to check this.


function imageLoaded() {
  console.log("Image loaded");
}
<img id="myimage" onload="imageLoaded()" src="https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/05/69/37/42/360_F_569374252_MibZowvlZC0fYV3eGCD9sXL9AYDlvKfd.jpg">



Onload in HTML,
<element onload="myScript">

In JavaScript:
object.onload = function(){myScript};

In JavaScript, using the addEventListener() method:
object.addEventListener("load", myScript);

For more reference: mdn,w3school
